# Ubuntu 20.04 android studio slow startup?

Tags: 20.04, android-studio

With the Ubuntu 20.04 released, I thought I'd switch from Windows for Android app development, So I did a fresh install on my SSD, then installed Android Studio from the snap store, but found that it takes a lot of time to startup compared to Windows, which I expected to be faster. On Ubuntu 20.04 android studio starts in a full 30 seconds while on Windows it only takes 5-7 seconds, so I decided to uninstall it, and downloaded from the official site, but the result was the same. Am I doing something wrong or what? cause I saw in other videos it starts just as fast on Windows, maybe a Ubuntu 20.04 issue I don't know please help if you have any insights

**Edit:** I tried to run the `studio.sh` script using sudo now the problem is fixed, but I do not find this solution satisfactory, I wanted it to work like normal without having to run as the root user, and having the SDK in the `/root/Android` directory.

Do anybody knows why running it as root speeds up the startup time(5 seconds)?

Comment: I have the same problem. This is Ubuntu 20.04 and Android Studio issue. There is no slow startup problem on 18.04. Other JetBrains IDEs startup times are normal on 20.04.

Comment: Thanks for commenting,if you find another solution please let me know 

Answer (score 4):

`sudo apt install appmenu-gtk2-module` and restart fixes it for me, it now starts up instantly. I'm using the snap version.

Comment: Wow! that solved the problem for me and I use non-snap version.

Comment: Still the same issue for me even after installing appmenu-gtk2-module... Android Studio takes 30+ seconds to start.

Comment: @gregoiregentil Did you restart the computer after installing?

Comment: Solved the problem too.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, startup is very slow compared to Ubuntu 19.10 for example.

I do not know if it is due to Ubuntu or Android Studio

Comment: Thanks for answering, I thought it was an issue only on my side,but I hope it gets fixed soon.

Answer (score 2):

I'm posting an answer that is mentioned in the edit of the question, not to try to gain some stackexchange points but to get visibility on this MAJOR issue.

**Yes, it's painfully slow.** On my Ubuntu 20.04 installation, the splash screen takes **25 to 30 seconds** to appear. Nothing is happening during this time, no CPU usage, no disk access, no download. My laptop is powerful (16GB ram, ssd, recent Intel CPU...)

And yes, if you start sudo studio.sh, the splash screen appears quasi immediately. Hahaha, the big joke!!!

I have spent hours to tweak everything and the problem persists. Android Studio is just completely bloatware. All the menus have dozens of items that I never use, the settings change at each MINOR iteration (so you are always lost), the settings are so hard to understand and to figure out (which option does what...). **Personally, the list of complaints against Android Studio is endless.**

Complete failure. Google, fix your stuff. Upvote this answer if you are dissatisfied with Android Studio on Ubuntu 20.04.

**SO TEMPORARY FIX IS TO START 'ANDROID STUDIO' AS ROOT".** Great move Google!!!

Comment: Honestly, I don't know if it's Google's, or Ubuntu's fault, after not being able to find another solution, I switched to other distros to test (Debian 10, pop_os! 20.04), and there's absolutely no issues there everything is running fast and smooth, currently I'm on pop_os! 20.04 which I find quite elegant.

Comment: I'd definitely discourage running Android Studio as root. Try the snap instead.

Comment: @LyteFM Why shouldn't we run android studio as root?

Comment: Just general safety considerations. It's always a good idea to run software - especially from 3rd parties - with restricted permissions so that possible damage to your system is limited if anything goes wrong. And there have been exploitable vulnerabilities in Android Studio in the past https://www.xda-developers.com/android-studio-eclipse-itellij-parsedroid-vulnerability/

Comment: It is rather a rant, not an answer.

Comment: @GregDan. Completely and I assume it. Google doesn't listen to the direct feed-back. Seeing the traffic on this question, I'm not the only one to be impacted by this MAJOR bug. Perhaps this thread/question will wake up the Android Studio team.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't experienced any longer startup times after upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04, it's still just a couple of seconds. But I'm running it as snap, not from a downloaded installation. Try uninstalling your current version and then:

```
sudo snap install android-studio --classic
```

For sure a better idea than running it as root...